# How to copy folders or files from remote instrument to that same instrument with python

Tags: python, remote-server

I am writing scripts to implement automation test with pyvisa package to communicate with instrument. However, I need to copy folders and files from the instrument to the same instrument. Pyvisa does not have the ability to do that. Please suggest what packages and commands I need to use. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming instrument is a computer?  You can work with remote machine through ssh and transferring file with scp.  Python have SCPClient and paramiko package that can do these.  This will allows you to ssh (secure shell) into the remote machine and execute commands.  The SCPClient allows you to transfer files to the remote machine or retrieve files from it.  For this to work, your remote machine need to have an ssh server running.

Comment: Thanks, I will learn and try.